# CURL and PHP to connect user with Facebook app

Tags: ajax, facebook, curl, firebug

receiving the Facebook username and password of our users via SMS we want to connect them with our Facebook app by using PHP and CURL only.

I got the CURL working to login the user and to navigates to the Facebook App Center.

But now, can anyone help me I to make the ajax url call using cURL and setting the variables to their proper values?

Many thanks in advance!

I used Firebug to get the http request header(example):

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  datr=uwFOULplg04OUafUhiZ0HuH3;
fr=01N5ffPgbtXUfTSbp.AWXd1IvmHVuGxr9GDRK9hpoYg
7g.BQTgHg.-8.AWXCZ9aq; lu=Rg6On5bhniBKFnROJOb7OApg; locale=en_GB;
c_user=100002533085804; csm=2; s=Aa5wBFIhYob4hVne.BQiowf;
xs=61%3AaaoKTpJSVJO6PA%3A2%3A1351257119; act=1351265044404%2F0%3A2; p=6;
presence=EM351265035EuserFA21B02533085804A2EstateFDsb2F0Et2F_5b_5dElm2
FnullEuct2F1351256551BEtrFA2loadA2EtwF1590615573EatF1351264924097G3512
65035755CEchFDp_5f1B02533085804F1CC; sub=34605056
Host    apps.facebook.com
Referer https://apps.facebook.com/thefind/?fb_source=search&fb_appcenter=1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1
X-SVN-Rev   656775
```

and the variables with their values:
     __a    1
    __user  100002533085804
    filter[0]   app
    filter[1]   page
    filter[2]   group
    filter[3]   friendlist
    lazy    1
    token   v7
    viewer  100002533085804

Answer (score 4):

You should not be collecting your user's password to log them in! This is a [TOS violation](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) and is a poor practice.

Instead, if you want to do this in PHP, you should be using the [server side login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/) method to authenticate your user. Once they complete this process, they will have authenticated your app.

Comment: Sorry for busting your bubble. I feel your pain. You can complain to me, but I'm only a volunteer here and don't have any internal relationship to Facebook. As far as the TOS, your app is a very clear violation of I.2. "You must not include functionality that proxies, requests or collects Facebook usernames or passwords" and I.3. "You must not circumvent our intended limitations on core Facebook features and functionality".